# How can I change my JLabel text muliple times?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel, mouselistener

I want to change my JLabel text multiple times without it overwrites itself when I select a new item on my list.

```
list.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}


                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
                {   



                    /**
                     *  Create a JLabel which shows the selected item.
                     */
                    String item = (String) list.getSelectedValue();

                    JLabel itemName = new JLabel(item);

                    itemName.setBounds(400, 50, 300, standardBtnHeight);
                    panel.add(itemName);

                    System.out.println("Showing: " + item);

                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
```

I just want the JLabel to show **one** item at the time but when I select an new item it just puts the new item name on top of the existing name. And when you've selected enough items, it's just a black bar.
Thanks

Regards,
Branders

Comment: Change the text of the existing `JLabel` instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Oh wow, was it really so simple. Thanks mah man!

Answer (score 1):

```
list.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                itemName.setText("text");
            }

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                itemName.setText("text");
            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                itemName.setText("text");
            }

            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                itemName.setText("text");
            }


            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { 
                itemName.setText("text");
            }
});
```